Angular to Spring Boot socket.io client netty socket.io
Here's my Angular Service
I am looking for other angular projects that uses the same package however their server is not spring boot
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {

private socket: any;
isBrowser = false;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)
if (this.isBrowser) {
  console.log("hello")
  this.initSocket();
}
}

private initSocket(): void {
this.socket = io('http://ipv4:8081');

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to Socket.IO server');
});

this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Disconnected from Socket.IO server');
});

this.socket.on('get_message', (data: any) => {
  // Handle incoming messages from the server
  console.log('Received message:', data);
  // You can emit events or update your application state here
});
}

sendMessage(room: string, message: any): void {

if (this.isBrowser) {

  this.initSocket();
  if (this.socket.connected) {
    this.socket.emit('send_message', { room, message });
  } else {
    console.error('Socket is not connected, cannot send message!');
  }
  } 
  }
  }

Here is my Spring Boot app
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SocketIOModule {


private final SocketIOServer server;
private final SocketIOService socketService;

public SocketIOModule(SocketIOServer server, SocketIOService socketService) {
    this.server = server;
    this.socketService = socketService;
    this.server.addConnectListener(onConnected());
    this.server.addDisconnectListener(onDisconnected());
    this.server.addEventListener("send_message", Message.class, onChatReceived());
}

private DataListener<Message> onChatReceived() {
    return (senderClient, data, ackSender) -> {
        log.info("Data: {}",data.toString());
        socketService.sendMessage(data.getRoom(),"get_message", senderClient, data.getMessage());
    };
}

private ConnectListener onConnected() {
    return (client) -> {

        log.info(String.valueOf(client.getHandshakeData()));
        final String roomVariable = client.getHandshakeData().getSingleUrlParam("room");
        final String room = Objects.nonNull(roomVariable)?roomVariable:"temp";
        log.info("Room: {}",room);
        client.joinRoom(room);
        log.info("Socket ID[{}]  Connected to socket", client.getSessionId().toString());
    };
}

private DisconnectListener onDisconnected() {
    return client -> {
        log.info("Client[{}] - Disconnected from socket", client.getSessionId().toString());
    };
}

}

i tried creating a mock server using node it connects properly however it seems like its having a problem connecting to the package of socket io my spring boot app is using
on the logs of spring boot the angular app is toggling between connected and disconnected
on the angular app its says Socket is not connected, cannot send message!
I want to send / receive message from angularalso room are not appended on the url when i check on network tab on browser been stuck on this problem for a long time. your answer is appreciated thanks
Angular to be able to send/receive data to the socket.io server
